# My double function doesnt give me a result back

Tags: function

I want to add 2 doubles in a function, but the function always gives me back 0.00000 whatever i do..

I want to print out the result or give it back at the end of the double (plus) function.

I know, there is a simpler way to add 2 doubles, but i wanted to specificly use a function to organize and structure my code better. Oh and yeah the stdio and stdlib .h are included in the original code..

```
double plus();

int main()
{
double a;
double b;
double result;
printf("Bitte geben Sie eine positive Zahl ein: ");
scanf("%lf", &a);
printf("Bitte geben Sie eine weitere positive Zahl ein: ");
scanf("%lf", &b);

plus();
printf("%f", result);
return 0;
}

double plus(double a, double b){

double result;
result = a + b;

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `plus` function is defined to have 2 double parameters:

`double plus(double a, double b){`

but you call the function without the parameters. Also your `plus` function returns a `result` and you did not capture it. The correct call in the `main` function should be:

`result = plus(a,b);`